# Warning on regex string in Python

Tags: r, python-3.x

So, I am doing a small function to strip all the weird chars from a string, eg. `#$&` will be replaced just for a `" "`

The chars I am trying to remove are the following, defined into a string: 
`xChars = r"#$%()'^*\;:/|+_.–°ªº"`

However I kepp getting the warning: 
`Anomalous backslash in string: '\;'. String constant might be missing an r prefix`

However, when i used the r prefix eg. `r"\"` python rules out some of the special chars i want to replace. It doesnt produce an error it just thinks that those chars are ok or something and it rules them out.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: You are not using a character class as well.

Answer (score 1):

Normally backslashes escape characters, therefore the compiler isn´t sure if the backslash has to be escaped. Maybe try using a double backslash to escape the backslash itself like: `xChars = r"#$%()'^*\\;:/|+_.–°ªº"`

Comment: If you actually wanted the regex to find "\", wouldn't you have to type "\\\\"?

Comment: not that i knew. If you are unsure about any regex try using tools like www.regex101.com

Comment: that site is awesome.  You're correct, the regex "\\\\" will find "\\".  My bad.